# Xamarin bundle referenced .net standard project content

Tags: ios, xamarin, .net-standard

I have a Xamarin iOS application. The iOS application references another project, a .NET Standard project. This project builds some resources (the assembly output is negligible). These resources are Content as that is what is in .NET Standard. The iOS application references this .NET Standard library.

When the iOS application is built, the .ipa file does not include the Content from the referenced assembly.

I've tried various things like hacking BundleResource to include the filepaths, but it wasn't effective as I could not get the new `<ProjectReference>` format to give me the filepaths of the output content, just the assembly.

How can I bundle the Content from my .NET Standard  assembly in my iOS application?

Comment: Have you tried including them as BundledResources instead?

Comment: You would need to include include those resources as "embedded resources" and read them from the assembly at runtime via GetManifestResourceStream

Comment: @Jason A little tricky since they can't be BundleResource in the original project as it is not an iOS project. I have tried some MSBuild-fu to convert them as BundleResource in the iOS project's build, but could not get this to work.

Comment: @SushiHangover I looked into this solution, but the API I am consuming really wants files on disk.

Comment: @Puppy You would either need to move these files to an Xamarin.iOS project (library or application based) and flagged them as bundle resources or copy them out of the assembly that they are embedded in (i.e. to the iOS app cache dir, or such, and then use them as "normal" files). Personally I avoid embedded resources due to runtime performance factors (constant memory bloat, etc...) and always prefer to use the native bundling features within the mobile app structure.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if `MyClass` is a class and `MyContent.txt` is a text file with property build action `Embeddeded resource`, both in the .NET Standard assembly `MyAssembly.NETStandard`, in the iOS assembly (iOS application):

```
var assembly = typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var filename = "MyAssembly.NETStandard.MyContent.txt";
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename);
var text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)) {
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The .NET Standard assembly `MyAssembly.NETStandard` must be referenced in the iOS assembly.

See also [Loading Files Embedded as Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=windows#loading-files-embedded-as-resources).

Comment: Unfortunately, the API I am consuming really wants files on disk. Perhaps it is possible to convince it to accept streams but this could be.. awkward.